# Django doesn't create migrate on my database

Tags: django

I have a project on Django. This project has an existing database on MySQL, the project has new change on my models, views, etc.

When I try to migrate it shows errors but doesn't create the new changes in my database.

I reset the migrations and try again but have the same problem.

Commandos that I run:

```
[root@server SistemaGestion]# find . -path "*/migrations/*.pyc"  -delete
[root@server SistemaGestion]# python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, contenttypes, auth, sessions
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
  Your models have changes that are not yet reflected in a migration, and so won't be applied.
  Run 'manage.py makemigrations' to make new migrations, and then re-run 'manage.py migrate' to apply them.
The following content types are stale and need to be deleted:

    areas | subproceso

Any objects related to these content types by a foreign key will also
be deleted. Are you sure you want to delete these content types?
If you're unsure, answer 'no'.

    Type 'yes' to continue, or 'no' to cancel: yes
[root@server SistemaGestion]# python manage.py makemigrations
Migrations for 'procesos':
  0001_initial.py:
    - Create model Colaboradores
Migrations for 'indicadores':
  0001_initial.py:
    - Create model Objetivos
...
...
...

[root@server SistemaGestion]# python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: procesos, indicadores, seguridad, admin, sessions, auth, personal, contenttypes, auditoria, normas, documentos, sac, areas
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
```

Comment: Because your django migration table has already applied initial migrations so use `python manage.py migrate --fake `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your tables already exist you should run `python manage.py migrate --fake-initial` after makemigrations. See the details in Django docs... https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/migrations/#adding-migrations-to-apps.